# Getting Error while deploying contract at my private network

Tags: stellar-core, smart-contract

I have set up a private network of stellar-core version 20.2.0. As 20.2.0 version supports soroban smart contract platform, so can I deploy smart contract to my private network. I have tried the same and getting below error

2024-03-08T09:24:01.554903Z ERROR soroban_cli::rpc: TXN failed:
Ok(
TxSorobanInvalid,
)
error: transaction submission failed: TxSorobanInvalid

Any help.